# Is there a way to handle clear event on text input in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am using a text input with data clear option.  Is there a way to handle the clear event so I can perform some cleanup task?

```
<input type="text" name="txbAppraisalAmount" id="txbAppraisalAmount" value="" data-clear-btn="true" data-mini="true"/>
```

Comment: jQM version 1.3.x or 1.4?

Comment: I use jquery mobile 1.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach event to `.ui-input-clear`.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function () {
  $(".ui-input-clear").on("click", function() {
    /* do what you want */
  });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Xm4FQ/)**

Comment: That works.  Is there a way to use it on an id instead of a class?

Comment: @bachdang no, because it's created dynamically. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I may have n number of text inputs.  Each may have different clear purposes.  If I apply wholesale using the class approach, they all get cleanup which may not be intended.  Using id would be the best solution.  However, your suggestion is very good.

Comment: this way, you can check the id of the input using `$(this).prev("input")[0].id` @bachdang

Answer (score 1):

This will handle a value change including a clear (although not in the midst of  a user typing):

```
$('#textInput').on('change', function() {
    /* ... */
});
```

If you want to handle just a clear, you can check for an empty value within the callback:

```
$('#textInput').on('change', function() {
    if($(this).val() === '') {
        /* ... */
    }
});
```

And if you wanted to handle value changes and clears regardless of whether the user is typing:

```
$('#textInput').on('change input', function() {
    if($(this).val() === '') {
        /* ... */
    }
});
```